# How to select the right columns in indexing for better performance

Tags: mysql

We are trying to retrieve data based on some conditions but the problem is for giving index to columns.
There are already some indexes but they are not being used.

The query:

```
select `UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`genericDemandId` AS `genericDemandId`,
    `UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`customerReference` AS `customerReference`,
    `UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`policyNumber` AS `policyNumber`,
    `UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`demandTypeId` AS `demandTypeId`,
    `UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`initiator` AS `initiator`,
    `UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`demandCreatedDateTime` AS `demandCreatedDateTime`,
    `UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`demandEndDateTime` AS `demandEndDateTime`,
    `UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`startDateTime` AS `startDateTime`,
    `UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`endDateTime` AS `endDateTime`,
    `UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`status` AS `status`,
    `UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`isUrgent` AS `isUrgent`,
    `UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`modifiedCreatedDateTime` AS `modifiedCreatedDateTime`,
    `UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`demandSource` AS `demandSource`,
    `UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`id` AS `Id`,
    `UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`schemeReference` AS `schemeReference`,
    `UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`categoryReference` AS `categoryReference`,
    `UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`aggregationKey` AS `aggregationKey` 
from `UK_Generic_Demand_Details` 
where (((`UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`customerReference` is not null) 
    and (`UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`customerReference` <> '') 
    and (`UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`policyNumber` is not null) 
    and (`UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`policyNumber` <> '') 
    and (`UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`genericDemandId` is not null)) 
    or ((`UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`schemeReference` is not null) 
    and (`UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`schemeReference` <> '') 
    and (`UK_Generic_Demand_Details`.`genericDemandId` is not null)))
```

The index that are present are:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `IX7_UK_Generic_Demand_Details` (`genericDemandId`),
 KEY `IX8_UK_Generic_Demand_Details` (`initiator`,`status`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX9_UK_Generic_Demand_Details` (`aggregationKey`,`status`,`genericDemandId`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX10_UK_Generic_Demand_Details` (`categoryReference`),
 KEY `IX11_UK_Generic_Demand_Details` (`aggregationKey`),
 KEY `IX1_UK_Generic_Demand_Details` (`status`,`aggregationKey`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX2_UK_Generic_Demand_Details` (`customerReference`),
 KEY `IX4_UK_Generic_Demand_Details` (`schemeReference`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX12_UK_Generic_Demand_Details` (`demandTypeId`,`contractSystem`,`productGroup`,`isBusinessException`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX3_UK_Generic_Demand_Details` (`policyNumber`,`demandTypeId`,`status`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX5_UK_Generic_Demand_Details` (`demandTypeId`,`demandId`) USING BTREE
```

The Explain of the query is :
[image]

Someone please suggest me in indexing the correct column to get better performance.

The full table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `UK_Generic_Demand_Details` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `policyNumber` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `customerReference` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `demandTypeId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `demandId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `initiator` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `startDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `endDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `isActive` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `demandCreatedDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `demandEndDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `documentUniqueReference` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `isUrgent` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `modifiedCreatedDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `demandSource` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `genericDemandId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `schemeReference` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
 `categoryReference` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
 `aggregationKey` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `contractSystem` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `productGroup` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `isBusinessException` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `IX7_UK_Generic_Demand_Details` (`genericDemandId`),
 KEY `IX8_UK_Generic_Demand_Details` (`initiator`,`status`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX9_UK_Generic_Demand_Details` (`aggregationKey`,`status`,`genericDemandId`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX10_UK_Generic_Demand_Details` (`categoryReference`),
 KEY `IX11_UK_Generic_Demand_Details` (`aggregationKey`),
 KEY `IX1_UK_Generic_Demand_Details` (`status`,`aggregationKey`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX2_UK_Generic_Demand_Details` (`customerReference`),
 KEY `IX4_UK_Generic_Demand_Details` (`schemeReference`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX12_UK_Generic_Demand_Details` (`demandTypeId`,`contractSystem`,`productGroup`,`isBusinessException`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX3_UK_Generic_Demand_Details` (`policyNumber`,`demandTypeId`,`status`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX5_UK_Generic_Demand_Details` (`demandTypeId`,`demandId`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35350 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Or suggest me if  there is any wrong in my query that need to be changed.

Comment: Please include table definition

Comment: Also, `KEY` is different from `INDEX`, so table definition **including** all index definitions is required to make any suggestions

Comment: Indexes are not going to help. Your query is essentially asking for all rows that have *some* info. That's always going to require a full table scan.

Comment: I guess KEY is not different from INDEX,it is just a synonym of index.

Comment: Any suggestions in changing the query to avoid the full table scan and get the required result with better performance?

Answer (score 0):

Indexes won't help you for that type of filtering conditions.

Let me introdice the quote that perhaps shed a light on the subject:

> Searching in a database index is like searching in a printed telephone
>   directory. The key concept is that all entries are arranged in a
>   well-defined order. Finding data in an ordered data set is fast and
>   easy because the sort order determines each entry's position.

You got the idea? Nulls/empties are simply out of scope, hence the engine is obliged to do a full scan through the table.

If that would have been a multimodel DB engine, it could potentially (!), at least, cluster nulls together thus avoid fetching these fields - but row model leaves you no chance.